# Ubuntu Server 22.04: CPU doesn't support virtualization, but VT-x is enabled in BIOS

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to run a headless virtualbox vm with Windows 10 on an Ubuntu Server 22.04 host. I have used virtualbox on this exact machine in the past (maybe about 2 years ago) and it worked. However, when I execute `vboxmanage startvm myvirtmachine --type headless` I get the following error message:

```
Waiting for VM "myvirtmachine" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

`Intel Virtualization Technology` was enabled in BIOS, but I loaded the default settings and explicitly enabled it again (couldn't find any `secure boot` settings to disable this too). Even after that, when I run `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` in the terminal I get `0` as a result (I read that if this returns more than zero, it means you CPU DOES support virtualization). I know my CPU supports virtualization, because I used virtualbox in the past on this machine. One thing that I read online is that Docker (it is indeed installed and running) uses Hyper-V which messes up with VT-x, but that corresponds to a Windows host system, and my case is not such. I installed `kvm` and when I run `kvm-ok` I get:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

How to tackle this problem, where should I look for clues? Could this be a kernel problem?

Edit:
The hardware I'm taking about is an old Lenovo b570 laptop with 4GB RAB and 2-core Intel Pentium CPU. Here is the output of `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:           x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:        36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 2
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0,1
Vendor ID:              GenuineIntel
  Model name:           Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz
    CPU family:         6
    Model:              42
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 2
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           7
    CPU max MHz:        2100.0000
    CPU min MHz:        800.0000
    BogoMIPS:           4190.33
    Flags:              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfm perf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
Caches (sum of all):    
  L1d:                  64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                  64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                   512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                   2 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                   
  NUMA node(s):         1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0,1
Vulnerabilities:        
  Itlb multihit:        KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
  L1tf:                 Mitigation; PTE Inversion
  Mds:                  Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Meltdown:             Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:      Not affected
  Retbleed:             Not affected
  Spec store bypass:    Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:           Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:           Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
  Srbds:                Not affected
  Tsx async abort:      Not affected
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include some of your system specs, including the exact model of your CPU? This will make it easier to answer your question accurately 

Comment: Edited the question and added some hardware specifications.

Comment: [According to Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/55627/intel-pentium-processor-b950-2m-cache-2-10-ghz.html), your processor does not support virtualisation. See the bottom section titled "Security & Reliability". VT-x is reported as "No" 

Comment: I have been using virtualbox in the past on this particular computer, so I know it supports virtualization. The problem is that the host operating system thinks it doesn't.

Comment: Same issue here with Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. I remember using Hyper V (Docker) on the same Lenovo Ideapad 720 (core i5-8250U) but on Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe the OS is causing the issue. Have you tried with another Ubuntu/Debian/Linux version?